# Multiply checkbox post php ajax return issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, checkbox

have code:

```js
  //$(document).ready(function () {

  function call() {

    var msg = new Array();

    $("input[name='uservalues[]']:checked").each(function() {
      msg.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(msg); //first log
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'res2.php',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: msg,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); //second log
        $('#results').html(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, str) {
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseCode);
      }
    });
    console.log(msg); //third log
  }
  //});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" id="formx" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">
  <input class="uservalues" type="checkbox" name="uservalues[]" value="9001" checked>user1
  <br>
  <input class="uservalues" type="checkbox" name="uservalues[]" value="9002" checked>user2
  <br>
  <input class="uservalues" type="checkbox" name="uservalues[]" value="9003">user3
  <br>
  <input class="uservalues" type="checkbox" name="uservalues[]" value="9011">user11
  <br>
  <input class="uservalues" type="checkbox" name="uservalues[]" value="9087" checked>user87
  <br>
  <input class="uservalues" type="checkbox" name="uservalues[]" value="9089">user89
  <br>
  <input class="uservalues" type="checkbox" name="uservalues[]" value="9096">user96
  <br>
  <input class="uservalues" type="checkbox" name="uservalues[]" value="9097">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Send">
</form>
<div id="results">output</div>
```

my res2.php

```
<?php
print_r ($_POST);
?>
```

So problem, that in console.log fist and third - i had `["9001", "9002", "9087"]` 
but in second log and in post return i had

```
Array ( [undefined] => )
```

Also when uncomment $(document).ready function with closing tags - i had error -

> Uncaught ReferenceError: call is not defined

Comment: try to change inside print_r to `$_POST['uservalues'];`

Comment: `print_r ($_POST['uservalues']);` - return blank

Answer (score 0):

I think you must pass the name like this:

```
$_POST['uservalues'];
```

Your function must be inside a script.

```
<script>
    //your function
</script>
```

Comment: function in in script, just posted here as separate

Comment: i think problem is in `$("input[name='uservalues[]']:checked").each(function () {
            msg.push($(this).val());
   //msg.push(this.value);
        });`
when change it to
`var msg = $('#formx').serialize();`
have such second log **Array ( [uservalues] => Array ( [0] => 9001 [1] => 9002 [2] => 9087 ) )**
Maybe this is error solving?

Comment: Don't answer here in the add comment section. Read this. http://www.wikihow.com/Answer-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Comment: thank you. Also make answer as you wrote. _P.S. sorry for my ugly English_